# Mask string with another pattern string

Tags: java, regex, string

I'd like to mask numbers according to pattern. If number is 22123123123 and pattern is xxxxx***xxx the result of masking should be 22123***123. I wrote a code:

```
private String maskNumberWithPattern(String number) {
    char[] pattern = "xxxxx***xxx".toCharArray();
    char[] numberInput = number.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        if(pattern[i] == '*') {
            stringBuffer.append("*");
        } else {
            stringBuffer.append(numberInput[i]);
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Is there some standard api method to achieve that?

Comment: Are you looking for a standardised way to apply your custom pattern to your Input? Otherwise if you just need to replace some numbers by stars, you could also use a regex to do that. And is this the only pattern type?

Comment: See the comment to rudi's answer.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing on standard api. That seems quite specific... Use your own code, there's nothing wrong on it. Another idea would be to change the conf to use start_stars and end_stars positions. And then create the new string with substrings... no reason to change to that new method tough...

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code how your pattern behaves exactly. For example, what should happen if the input String is longer than your pattern? Is there a chance that the pattern does not match? Etc. I don't know such thing...

I guess wildcard patterns or regular expression is the easiest thing you can get here:

```
private static String maskNumberWithPattern(String number) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{5})(\\d*)(\\d{3})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String group = matcher.group(2);
        return matcher.group(1) + StringUtils.repeat('*', group.length()) + matcher.group(2);
    }
    else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pattern and string will be always same length. Rule for pattern is simple, if there is x in pattern leave digit on that position in input string, if there is asterisk in pattern replace digit with asterisk. I was using simple regex earlier, but now I need to apply such pattern from configuration. I don't want to use regexp, cause someone who does not know regexps should be abble to change the pattern in conf.

Comment: Never heard of such a requirement. I guess then your implementation is the best you can get. (Although you could improve it by using a `char[]` instead a StringBuilder.) In my experience such tiny "util tasks" are not worth adding a dependency to your project.

Comment: I agree totally with rudi.